# Terraform within modules lifecycle ignore changes on tags (timestamp) not ignoring

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Terraform v0.12.13 with provider.azurerm v1.36.1

I've got a number of modules that take common tags passed into them as `var.default.tags` merge then with local tags one of which is `timestamp()`. My modules will often have multiple resources listed in them to be changed.

This is working ok and everything tags correctly.

However, on subsequent `terraform apply` the tags on every resource get updated - eg the `timestamp` even if the change has not affected that particular resource in the module.

I understand that I can use lifecycle `ignore-changes` as per my code example below. Everything validates and applies ok, however the `lifecycle` seems to get ignored.

Any ideas?

```
tags = "${merge(
      var.default-tags,
      map(
        "Name", "${local.nameprefix}-this",
        "TF-last-modified", "${timestamp()}"
        )
      )}"
    lifecycle {
      ignore_changes = [
        tags["TF-last-modified"]
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I should also add I have tried putting the timestamp as a global variable ( Which I'd prefer) but I still see the same issue.

Comment: I have a feeling that `ignore_changes` is designed to ignore changes on the resources themselves, not changes within the script.

Comment: According to the documentation, what you wrote in the question should work. Therefore, the most likely explanation is that either something outside of the provided information is causing an issue, or you have hit on a bug and should file an issue on the Terraform tracker. I do note that the `ignore_changes` works on `update` operations on specific keys and not `create/destroy`, so maybe the dynamic generation here is causing the issue.

Comment: @JamesThorpe, Ye that's what it's supposed to do - having a tag of a timestamp is an automatic change to the resource every time, hence the need to ignore that change and only update when other values are changed.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, yeah that's not a bad call, I'll test by making the tags static for now and see what happens"

Comment: That's the thing though - as far as Terraform is concerned, you're wanting to change the resource because you're feeding it a new timestamp.  `ignore_changes` makes terraform ignore things _it didn't do_, not ignore things that it _wants_ to do.